# An open ball is an open set by the continuity of the norm

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

I Hvev an exercise that I should prove that in a normed space, an open ball is an open set, but using the property of the continuity of the norm.

Given a normed space $X$ and the norm $||.||$ such as $||.||\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, take $v \in X$ and $r>0$. Is $B_r(v) \subseteq X$ an open set?

To prove that the norm is continuous was not difficult. My idea was to create an interval in $\mathbb{R}$ and use the continuity by open sets to show that the ball is open: take $r>0$  in $\mathbb{R}$ and form the open interval:$(||v||-r, ||v||+r)$.

For any $a \in X$, $a \in B_r(v)$, we have, by the triangle inequality:  $|$||a||-||v||$|$$\leq ||a-v|| < r $. Therefore, $f^{-1} B_r(||v||)\subseteq B_r(v)$

I tried to prove the opposite, $B_r(v) \subseteq f^{-1} B_r(||v||)$, by contradiction: suppose that exists $p \in X$ such as:
$$ |||p||-||v||| <r$$
  $$||p-v||>r$$
But I got stuck in the process. Is is possible to prove that way, or there is something that I should see?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a ball around the origin:

$$B_r(0) = f^{-1}([0, r)),$$ where $f(x) = ||x||,$ and $[0,r)$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^+$ with the induced topology. So we have that any ball around the origin is open.

Similarly: $$ B_r(v) = f_v^{-1}([0, r)), $$ where $f_v(x) = ||x-v||.$ Since $f_v$ is continuous (why is it?) you get the result.